# How to implement progressBar while loading data?

Tags: android, background, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I want to implement progressBar like on the picture below.

Right now, I have AsyncTask whic is sperated from fragments classes, and I use that AsyncTask to load data, and right now I have implement progressBar dialog, but I want to get rid of that, because I want make a better UX.

I show that ProgressBar dialog in onPreExecute() method, and then dismiss it onPostExecute.

So, how I can implement background Progress bar like on the picture below

[image]

Comment: I guess you should take a look at this library https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dude,

If you really just want a progress bar like the picture you posted, you can simply set the progress bar **indeterminate** property to true :)

You can eighter do on code or directly on the xml.

In code:

```
yourProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

In your XML, just set the attribute indeterminate to true.

Here's is a simple layout as an example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hm, I stil get visible ProgressBar dialog, instead of showing progressBar in background as on the picture above.

Comment: My bad, I used progressDialog instead of ProgressBar, but anyway how I colud show it onPreExecute, or dismiss onPostExecute.

Comment: Did you also tried changing the visibility attribute? Every view has this attribute...

Comment: I use pb.setVisible(View.VISIBLE) in onPreExecute, and pb.setVisible(View.GONE) onPostExecute. Then, I added progressBar to the XML file of fragment, and using constructor of AsyncTask I made reference between progressBar in fragment with the one in AsyncTask class.

Comment: So, I didn't get your problem. Why don't you just stop using the progress dialog and start using a progress bar. You could do the same thing you're doing now. Show an indeterminate progress bar on preExecute, do your stuff, and get rid on the progress bar on  postExecute.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show progress, take a look at this code. This might give you an idea:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    myTask mytask = new myTask();
    Button button1;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mytask.execute();
    }

    class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressbar.setProgress(0);
            progressbar.setMax(100);
            int progressbarstatus = 0;
        };

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressbar.incrementProgressBy(10);
            }
            return "completed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

But if you want to show like a dialog, take a look at this code:

```
public class YoutubeVideoMain extends Activity {

    ListView videolist;

    ArrayList<String> videoArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> videoadapter;
    Context context;
    String feedURL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/twistedequations/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=5";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.youtubelist);
        videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videolist);

        videoadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.video_list_item,
                videoArrayList);

        videolist.setAdapter(videoadapter);
        VideoListTask loadertask = new VideoListTask();
        loadertask.execute();

    }

    private class VideoListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        ProgressDialog dialogue;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialogue.dismiss();

            videoadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialogue = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialogue.setTitle("Loading items..");
            dialogue.show();
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(feedURL);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                StatusLine statusline = response.getStatusLine();
                int statuscode = statusline.getStatusCode();

                if (statuscode != 200) {

                    return null;
                }

                InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    builder.append(line);

                }
                String jsonData = builder.toString();



                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);


                JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

                JSONArray items = data.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject video = items.getJSONObject(i);



                    videoArrayList.add(video.getString("title"));



                }

                Log.i("YouJsonData:", jsonData);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Maybe this can help you.

Comment: I am afraid that this code cant help me a lot, because I use seperate class for AsyncTask.

Comment: You can still have the instance of AsyncTask class in your main Class right.

Comment: Anyways the concept will be same. Your main class is anyways going to call the AsncTask when the app is launched so dialog box will be displayed through the AsyncTask class in your case.

Comment: I don't want dialog to be displayed, just progressBar in background, as you can see on the picture above.

Comment: I can't create a progressBar instance in some fragment class and then access to that progrssBar from my AsyncTask class.

Comment: I think I get the prob now. Maybe I'll have to think about it little more. Sorry about the code.

Answer (score 0):

With the same asynctask using [publishProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29)

Comment: I dont use publishProgress(), just call ProgressBar Dialog onPreExecute, and then dismiss it in onPostExecute.

Comment: That means that the async task should have a reference to the view that could get disposed (nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourCLassName extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Files.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setTitle("your message");

        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // YOUR PIECE OF CODE

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


            pd.setMessage("Task Completed  .. whatever");


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


}
```

Comment: Your code is similar to mike20132013's code, so I can't implement it like that, because my AsyncTask class is seperated from class where I load data.

Comment: and its a `ProgressDialog` not `ProgressBar`

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 26.
ProgressDialog is a modal dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively, you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress.