# Swipe lag issue with Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, lag

[image]

I have a problem with the viewpager navigation. It hangs during the transition from one page to another. (Laggy). You can see above the simplified architecture of my code. I understood that AsyncTask were the problem since these processes communicate with UIThread. My asynctaks update fragment views. So, is it possible both to navigate very smoothly with viewpager and simultaneously update views?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a specific answer without seeing your code, but :

AsyncTask are only supposed to touch the UI thread in the onPostExecute method, and that should be used to **update** your UI once the task is complete. You should set a default UI to be shown as soon as your Fragment is created and update the UI when the task is complete. If you can't show any content before getting data from the AsyncTask, you can set the Fragment's view to show a ProgressBar and hide that to show your data when you have it (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854060/how-to-implement-progressbar-while-loading-data) for details).

I hope this helps ;) Let me know if you need more explanation ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you do not answer to my problem, my problem is swippe lag...the issue is to synchronize the swippe and updated views

Comment: You're saying in your question that your AsynTask communicate with the UI thread... Your lag is likely due to your UI thread hanging somewhere, probably because you are blocking it with code that should not be executing on that thread. Did you check the question I'm linking to ? Unless you pre-load your data before even getting to the viewpager screen, you probably will have to consider my solution.